# In Python 3.x, why is there not an itertools shared-object on disk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, python-internals

Is the [itertools C module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c) included somehow in the main Python binary in 3.x?

Assuming that the C module is built and included, which it appears to be:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> import itertools
>>>
>>> inspect.getsourcefile(itertools)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/inspect.py", line 571, in getsourcefile
    filename = getfile(object)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/inspect.py", line 518, in getfile
    raise TypeError('{!r} is a built-in module'.format(object))
TypeError: <module 'itertools' (built-in)> is a built-in module
```

I can't find an `itertools.so` for Python 3.x on my system, but there's one for 2.7.

I noted that some other C modules exist as shared objects (`locate '.so' | grep -E '^/usr/local/' | grep '.so'` e.g. `mmap.so`) on disk,  so what's the deal with `itertools`?  How can I use it if there's not a shared library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are hints in the makefile that's near the Python wrapper of `inspect.py`:

`/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m/Makefile`

We can see the build rules for the itertools.c source:

```
1668 Modules/itertoolsmodule.o: $(srcdir)/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c; $(CC) $(PY_CORE_CFLAGS)  -c $(srcdir)/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c -o      Modules/itertoolsmodule.o
```

And then trace it a little to see that it's being bundled in:

```
 24 MODOBJS= ..  Modules/itertoolsmodule.o  ... Modules/xxsubtype.o

 462 # objects that get linked into the Python library
 463 LIBRARY_OBJS_OMIT_FROZEN=   \
...
 470         $(MODOBJS)
 471
 472 LIBRARY_OBJS=   \
 473         $(LIBRARY_OBJS_OMIT_FROZEN) \
 474         Python/frozen.o
 ...
 553 # Build the interpreter
 554 $(BUILDPYTHON): Modules/python.o $(LIBRARY) $(LDLIBRARY) $(PY3LIBRARY)
 555     $(LINKCC) $(PY_LDFLAGS) $(LINKFORSHARED) -o $@ Modules/python.o $(BLDLIBRARY) $(LIBS) $(MODLIBS) $(SYSLIBS) $(LDLAST)
 556
 557 platform: $(BUILDPYTHON) pybuilddir.txt
 558     $(RUNSHARED) $(PYTHON_FOR_BUILD) -c 'import sys ; from sysconfig import get_platform ; print(get_platform()+"-"+sys.version[0:     3])' >platform
 589 # Build static library
 ...
 598     $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(MODOBJS)
 599     $(RANLIB) $@

 944 $(LIBRARY_OBJS) $(MODOBJS) Modules/python.o: $(PYTHON_HEADERS)
```

Or if made via `distutils`, the path will be something like: `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/_sysconfigdata.py`

And assuming that this gets built into a dynamic library:

```
Ξ ~ → strings /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/libpython3.4.dylib | grep itertools
itertools
itertools._tee_dataobject
itertools._tee
itertools._grouper
itertools.groupby
itertools.repeat
itertools.product
...
```

Which means that at build time, the itertools.c module gets included in the `libpython` dynamic library, meaning that it's now part of the standard library.

Answer (score 6):

In Python 3, the `itertools` extension is compiled into the main Python binary:

```
>>> import sys
>>> 'itertools' in sys.builtin_module_names
True
```

See the [`sys.builtin_module_names` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names):

> A tuple of strings giving the names of all modules that are compiled into this Python interpreter.

The module was added to the Python binary because it is used *very* widely in the Python standard library.

The list of modules to include is taken from the [`Modules/Setup.dist` file](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Modules/Setup.dist) in the Python distribution; `itertools` was added together with `_collections`, as it is a transient dependency of that module. See [issue #9545](http://bugs.python.org/issue9545).