# module 'itertools' has no attribute '__file__'

Tags: python, python-itertools

I would like to use the itertools module, but I am not sure whether it is up and running. I found nothing in /usr/lib/python*. (2.7 and 3.5 are available, on my system and under a few VirtualEnv's). I found no duplicate question about this.

I tried on my system:

```
alexandre@Martin-2:~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:51:06) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['itertools']
<module 'itertools' (built-in)>
>>> import itertools
>>> itertools.__file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'itertools' has no attribute '__file__'
>>> quit()
```

Any hint please?

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about the dup, but the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883364/in-python-3-x-why-is-there-not-an-itertools-shared-object-on-disk link was not tagged with itertools, so my research didn't show it up.